# How do I make a chart in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-office

None of the templates have chart as an option, but in the Play Store it stated you can do make charts. Where or how do I make a chart with a particular number of rows, etc?

Answer (score 3):

#### Short Answer

No, you cannot create a Chart using [Microsoft Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.word) for Android.
However, You can create Chart using [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel) for Android.

---

#### Long Answer

If there was any, it should have been under **Insert** menu which does not have *Charts* currently

[image: No charts in Word]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

There is no option to create charts in [Microsoft Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.word). Without any Office 365 subscription, Office for free - can render if you have a file which has customized chart (which has been created earlier using Microsoft Word on PC). Basic operations like Copy,Paste and delete works on charts.
See screenshot for more understanding

[image: Chart in Word free]
<sub>Blue tint in Status bar is Microsoft Word, green implies Microsoft Excel</sub>

---

#### Possible Workaround

You can however use [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel) for android to create Charts.

[image: Excel 1]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

---

#### About Playstore desciption

Microsoft has a unusual way of putting things about the apps in Google Play.
If you see [Microsoft Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.word) and [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel) Google play links and scroll down to the
**What's New** section
You'll see that they are literally identical and talks about the other i.e in [Microsoft Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.word) page they have mentioned about Excel's new features and in [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel) page they have mentioned about Word's new features too.

---

#### Office 365 subscription

Premium feature related to Charts

> **Advanced editing of charts**: precise control over chart display options that allow you to change elements of the chart such as data labels and the legend are paid features. If you use Office for free and receive a workbook which contains as customized chart, it will render in your Excel app. However, you will not be able to change chart elements unless you purchase a subscription.
>   [Source](http://venturebeat.com/2014/11/06/microsoft-makes-office-mobile-editing-free-launches-separate-iphone-apps-and-preview-for-android-tablets/)